# Android AutoComplete Textview enter character return all words of in listview android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In normal `AutoCompleteTextView` with `ListView` which return first letter of word in list.

But I need all word of list.

For example

I have list of data as follows,

```
ananthi
qwerty 
vasanthi
ravi
```

When enter "a" it should return,

```
ananthi
vasanthi
ravi
```

When enter "an" it should return,

```
ananthi
vasanthi
```

But in my code when I Enter "a" it return only,

```
ananthi
```

My Code is as follows,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String[] AndroidDesk= {"ananthi","qwerty ","vasanthi","ravi"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> My_arr_adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,AndroidDesk);
        AutoCompleteTextView My_auto_Cmplt_Tv=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autotv);
        My_auto_Cmplt_Tv.setThreshold(2);
        My_auto_Cmplt_Tv.setAdapter(My_arr_adapter);
        My_auto_Cmplt_Tv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(CharSequence)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: possible. have you tried [Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113650/5588347)? The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032707/custom-autocompletetextview-behavior) is similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

AutoCompleteTextView works only from starting character of a string, not from middle of any character of the string.

Ofcourse, it will return only "ananthi" if you enter "a".

Comment: what i can do for this result

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032707/custom-autocompletetextview-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I have refered this link it was useull   https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite/