# Proper ArrayAdapter implementation for an AutoCompleteTextView that doesn't just search the start of the String

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview, android-filter

The Default ArrayAdapter only checks, if the possible suggestions starts with the current input (it uses `.startsWith`. It doesn't use `.contains`. However I would like it to use `.contains`.

I already know about these two threads:

- [Custom AutoCompleteTextView behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032707/custom-autocompletetextview-behavior)
- [AutoCompleteTextView not completing words inside parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926034/autocompletetextview-not-completing-words-inside-parentheses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, these don't really do what I want them to do. All of them have at least one of these problems:

**1. The ArrayAdapter Class extends `ThemedSpinnerAdapter` which requires API level 23**

Downloading the sourcecode of the ArrayAdapter class and changing stuff in there, would be limited to API level 23 and up, because I can't find the ArrayAdapter for older versions.

**2. When the list object gets updated from outside the adapter after the constructor has been called, the suggestions don't get updated**

The best possible way I see to work around this is, overriding the `notifyDataSetChanged` function. In that function I would then just copy the current Items in the list from the constructor into the temporary list that contains all the items that should be filtered through.
However, the `notifyDataSetChanged` function also gets called from the `Filter.publishResults` function, thereby causing the 3rd problem.

**3. anything that was part of the list but didn't get suggested, will never appear again**

To change what is shown, the list from the constructor has to be changed. However, this change has to be somehow undoable. The best way I know to do this would be to add a second list, that contains all the items from the first one, but the list object itself is a different one. But then this list has to be kept up to date somehow (That's the 2nd problem).

An implementation that suffers from the 3rd problem:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Filter
import androidx.annotation.IdRes
import androidx.annotation.LayoutRes

class CustomStringArrayAdapter(
    context: Context,
    @LayoutRes resource: Int,
    @IdRes textViewResourceId: Int = 0,
    private val objects: List<String> = ArrayList()
) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects) {
    
    inner class CustomStringFilter : Filter() {
        
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            
            if (!constraint.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val suggestions = mutableListOf<String>()
                for (element in objects) {
                    if (element.contains(constraint, true)) {
                        suggestions.add(element)
                    }
                }
                
                filterResults.values = suggestions
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size
            }
            
            return filterResults
        }
        
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            if (results == null || results.count <= 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                return
            }
            
            val resultsValues = results.values
            if (resultsValues !is List<*>) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                return
            }
            
            val result = mutableListOf<String>()
            for (resultValue in resultsValues) {
                if (resultValue is String) {
                    result.add(resultValue)
                }
            }
            
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
            } else {
                clear()
                addAll(result)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private lateinit var mFilter: Filter
    
    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        if (!::mFilter.isInitialized) {
            mFilter = CustomStringFilter()
        }
        return mFilter
    }
    
}
```

An implementation that suffers from the 2nd problem:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Filter
import androidx.annotation.IdRes
import androidx.annotation.LayoutRes

class CustomStringArrayAdapter(
    context: Context,
    @LayoutRes resource: Int,
    @IdRes textViewResourceId: Int = 0,
    private val objects: List<String> = ArrayList()
) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects) {
    
    inner class CustomStringFilter : Filter() {
        
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            
            if (!constraint.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val completeList = tempObjects.toList()
                filterResults.values = completeList
                filterResults.count = completeList.size
            } else {
                val suggestions = mutableListOf<String>()
                for (element in tempObjects) {
                    if (element.contains(constraint, true)) {
                        suggestions.add(element)
                    }
                }
                
                filterResults.values = suggestions
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size
            }
            
            return filterResults
        }
        
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            if (results == null || results.count <= 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                return
            }
            
            val resultsValues = results.values
            if (resultsValues !is List<*>) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                return
            }
            
            val result = mutableListOf<String>()
            for (resultValue in resultsValues) {
                if (resultValue is String) {
                    result.add(resultValue)
                }
            }
            
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
            } else {
                clear()
                addAll(result)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private lateinit var mFilter: Filter
    private val tempObjects = objects.toMutableList()
    
    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        if (!::mFilter.isInitialized) {
            mFilter = CustomStringFilter()
        }
        return mFilter
    }
    
}
```

And another implementation that suffers from the 3rd problem:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Filter
import androidx.annotation.IdRes
import androidx.annotation.LayoutRes

class CustomStringArrayAdapter(
    context: Context,
    @LayoutRes resource: Int,
    @IdRes textViewResourceId: Int = 0,
    private val objects: List<String> = ArrayList()
) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects) {
    
    inner class CustomStringFilter : Filter() {
        
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            
            if (!constraint.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val completeList = tempObjects.toList()
                filterResults.values = completeList
                filterResults.count = completeList.size
            } else {
                val suggestions = mutableListOf<String>()
                for (element in tempObjects) {
                    if (element.contains(constraint, true)) {
                        suggestions.add(element)
                    }
                }
                
                filterResults.values = suggestions
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size
            }
            
            return filterResults
        }
        
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            if (results == null || results.count <= 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                return
            }
            
            val resultsValues = results.values
            if (resultsValues !is List<*>) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                return
            }
            
            val result = mutableListOf<String>()
            for (resultValue in resultsValues) {
                if (resultValue is String) {
                    result.add(resultValue)
                }
            }
            
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
            } else {
                clear()
                addAll(result)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private lateinit var mFilter: Filter
    private val tempObjects = objects.toMutableList()
    
    override fun notifyDataSetChanged() {
        tempObjects.clear()
        tempObjects.addAll(objects)
        super.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    
    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        if (!::mFilter.isInitialized) {
            mFilter = CustomStringFilter()
        }
        return mFilter
    }
    
}
```

Comment: At least until now, the only way I was really able to make this work is Downloading the source code of the ArrayAdapter class and turning it into a custom class. However I don't want to keep it that way, because I would have to react to every single change Google makes to that class. Also I had to remove the `implements ThemedSpinnerAdapter` part and all the functions that override functions from the `ThemedSpinnerAdapter`. So, this really can't be a long term solution.